# GPU fan boosts intermittently at idle

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu

I've recently installed Archbang Linux, although I recently had Manjaro XFCE and had this same problem. My GPU fan (Asus Nvidia GTX 750 ti) keeps boosting up intermittently while the computer is in light use or even idle. It seems to do this after the fan has stopped down to zero RPM and when the temperature starts to increase slightly. I am not sure what is causing it, especially as the GPU is not in heavy use and the boosting happens when the GPU temperature is about 36-37 C. I have tried reseating the GPU, as well as changing the thermal paste on the GPU chip and disconnecting/reconnecting the fan connector on the GPU, but all to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. I am wondering whether it might be a driver issue as the card is now quite old?

Other details:

Computer make: Fujitsu Esprimo P500

Processor: Intel Core i5 2400

Memory: 12 GB